# SQLite database is not open in real device but it opens in the emulator

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I implemented one code for SQLite database which is running successfully on android emulator but that is not running on the real device. and it shows error table not found. I created the database using SQLite browser and import the database in Android Device Monitor(fileExplorer>data>data>>database).  please check the following code and tell me where I am wrong. thankyou.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quiz6to8";
private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "tbl_cvs6";
//private static final String TABLE_SCIENCE = "science";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; //option a
private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; //option b
private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; //option c
private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; //option d
private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dbase=db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
            +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTD+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
    onCreate(db);
}

public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    dbase=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question quest = new Question();
            //quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(0));
            quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setOPTD(cursor.getString(4));
            quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(5));
            quesList.add(quest);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return quest list
    return quesList;
}

public int rowcount(){
    int row= 0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + "tbl_cvs6";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    row=cursor.getCount();
    return row;
  }
}
```

[stacktrace image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3hCw.png)

```
question.java class
public class Question {
private int ID;
private String QUESTION;
private String OPTA;
private String OPTB;
private String OPTC;
private String OPTD;
private String ANSWER;

public Question() {
    ID=0;
    QUESTION="";
    OPTA="";
    OPTB="";
    OPTC="";
    OPTD="";
    ANSWER="";
}

public Question(String qUESTION, String oPTA, String oPTB, String oPTC, String oPTD, String aNSWER) {

    QUESTION = qUESTION;
    OPTA = oPTA;
    OPTB = oPTB;
    OPTC = oPTC;
    OPTD = oPTD;
    ANSWER = aNSWER;
}

public int getID()
{
    return ID;
}
public String getQUESTION() {
    return QUESTION;
}
public String getOPTA() {
    return OPTA;
}
public String getOPTB() {
    return OPTB;
}
public String getOPTC() {
    return OPTC;
}
public String getOPTD() {
    return OPTD;
}
public String getANSWER() {
    return ANSWER;
}
public void setID(int id)
{
    ID=id;
}
public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
    QUESTION = qUESTION;
}
public void setOPTA(String oPTA) {
    OPTA = oPTA;
}
public void setOPTB(String oPTB) {
    OPTB = oPTB;
}
public void setOPTC(String oPTC) {
    OPTC = oPTC;
}
public void setOPTD(String oPTD) {
    OPTD = oPTD;
}
public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
    ANSWER = aNSWER;
}
```

}

Comment: try changing your database version

Comment: not working i changed it version 3 and it shows error no such table tbl_cvs6 while compling:select*from tbl_cvs6

Comment: Pass correct table name  as this doesn't exist `tbl_cvs6`

Comment: i changed it but not working

Comment: This is no longer a database problem. You are getting an `IndexOutofBoundsException` for your arraylist.

Comment: but its workig in emulator not showing this error . error only showing when app runs on device

Answer (score 2):

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quiz6to8";
private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "tbl_cvs6";
//private static final String TABLE_SCIENCE = "science";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; //option a
private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; //option b
private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; //option c
private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; //option d

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
            +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTD+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
    onCreate(db);
}

public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question quest = new Question();
            //quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(0));
            quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setOPTD(cursor.getString(4));
            quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(5));
            quesList.add(quest);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return quest list
    return quesList;
}

public int rowcount(){
    int row= 0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + "tbl_cvs6";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    row=cursor.getCount();
    return row;
  }
}
```

Replace your code with this and check once.

Comment: please check the updated codewhere i added stacktrece imge of logcat

Comment: Can you send that bean class

Comment: please can you tell where is the bean class locate

Comment: Question this class

Comment: public Question() {
   
}

Create empty constructor.Remove values inside this constructor

Comment: public Question() {
   
}

Comment: not working .  its run on emulator but not working on android devide

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall app and install it again and try once or i think drop table is not working here.
Try like this :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    dbase=db;
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
    onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: And your table name is "question" 
 String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "question";

Comment: Check newly added answer

Answer (score 0):

You are querying a non-existent table. You are trying to query a table named `tbl_cvs6` but you are only creating one table named `question` as defined by your constant TABLE_QUEST.

You need to create the tale before querying on it.

EDIT:
Its is likely that you created `tbl_cvs6` for the initial version of the database that was run on the emulator but not on the device. In further updates, you probably removed that code to create the said table. If you have SCM enabled, consider reviewing the code change from DB version 1 to 3.

Comment: Post the latest stack trace. Also, you don't need to call `getReadableDatabase()` and getWritableDatabase() and store it in the same reference. Writable reference allows you to both read and write. You need separate references only if you are accessing the database from multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: please check the updated code where i added the stacktrace image

Answer (score 0):

In my activity i am adding and checking it

```
public class QuestionClass extends Activity {
    List<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

            list = dbHelper.getAllQuestions();
            if (list.size() < 1) {
                dbHelper.addContact(new Question("KEY_QUES", "KEY_Ans", "KEY_OA", "KEY_OB", "KEY_OC", "KEY_OD"));
                Toast.makeText(this, "Add", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "SIze more", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("list", list.size() + "");

            }
```

Then in my DbHandler i am giving like this

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quiz6to8";
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "tbl_cvs6";
    //private static final String TABLE_SCIENCE = "science";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; //option c
    private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; //option d

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTD+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addContact(Question contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, contact.getQUESTION()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, contact.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, contact.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, contact.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, contact.getOPTC());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, contact.getOPTD());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                //quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(0));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTD(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }

    public int rowcount(){
        int row= 0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + "tbl_cvs6";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

Question class

```
public class Question {
    private int ID;
    private String QUESTION;
    private String OPTA;
    private String OPTB;
    private String OPTC;
    private String OPTD;
    private String ANSWER;

    public Question(String key_ques, String key_ans, String key_oa, String key_ob, String key_oc, String key_od) {
        this.QUESTION=key_ques;
        this.ANSWER=key_ans;
        this.OPTA=key_oa;
        this.OPTB=key_ob;
        this.OPTC=key_oc;
        this.OPTD=key_od;
    }

    public Question() {

    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getQUESTION() {
        return QUESTION;
    }

    public void setQUESTION(String QUESTION) {
        this.QUESTION = QUESTION;
    }

    public String getOPTA() {
        return OPTA;
    }

    public void setOPTA(String OPTA) {
        this.OPTA = OPTA;
    }

    public String getOPTB() {
        return OPTB;
    }

    public void setOPTB(String OPTB) {
        this.OPTB = OPTB;
    }

    public String getOPTC() {
        return OPTC;
    }

    public void setOPTC(String OPTC) {
        this.OPTC = OPTC;
    }

    public String getOPTD() {
        return OPTD;
    }

    public void setOPTD(String OPTD) {
        this.OPTD = OPTD;
    }

    public String getANSWER() {
        return ANSWER;
    }

    public void setANSWER(String ANSWER) {
        this.ANSWER = ANSWER;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working for me.Got list size too.Did u uninstall and install it again?

Comment: In activity you should create object of DbHandler .The call the method.